# How can I pass a string list of parameters to a function and have them assigned as separate arguments

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

How can I call `myFunc` in the below Javascript?

```
var myParams = "'a','b','c','d'";
myFunc(myParams); // myFunc("'a','b','c','d'");
```

Whereas I want it to act like:

```
myFunc('a','b','c','d');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**apply()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
var x = "'a','b','c','d'";
var args = x.split(',');
myfunc.apply(null, args);
```

This would be equivalent to

```
myfunc('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

**Update**

> When I call directly the alert just shows the value without enclosing
>   any quotes. But by your method it shows the value enclosed with single
>   quotes like 'a'

```
var args = x.replace(/[']+/g, '').split(',');
```

Comment: Thanks.  I believe I need to remove all the single quote... Because when the same method called directly the arguments are passed as values.  However in your method the arguments are passed as strings with single quotes like 'a'

Comment: @Malaiselvan, do you mean that `a` and `b` and `c` and `d` are actually variables?

Comment: Those are hardcoded values.  I just put an alert message inside my function.  When I call directly the alert just shows the value without enclosing any quotes.  But by your method it shows the value enclosed with single quotes like 'a'

Comment: @Malaiselvan, do you want like what is in my updated answer?

Comment: your solution works but not sure what will happen if the value itself contains a single quote.  Explained my question in jsfiddle and added the link in my question.